# where is the second electrode in case of electrostimulation

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neurophysiology, electrophysiology

With electrostimulation or functional electrostimulation, a response from the neuron is generated by electrical impulses.

But I always read, for example, that a stimulating electrode is above position xy of the neuron (e.g. above the axon), but in order for current to flow, there must be a closed circuit? i.e. if cathodic stimulation is used (e.g. with a -0.5mA pulse lasting 0.05ms), then there must be an anodic pole somewhere so that the current can flow, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Current flows from a high potential to a low potential, so if you inject a great deal of current via an electrode it will still flow into the body. However, even in the case of unipolar setups for deep brain stimulation (DBS), a second electrode is used, but relatively far away from the first one. Doing it this way is quite uncommon though: most electrical stimulation uses two poles (or even more), as it limits the spread of current to unwanted areas.

[image: Monopolar vs bipolar deep brain stimulation]

Transcranial direct current stimulation (tDCS) will for instance use an electrode on one side of the scalp and one on the other side.

Comment: There's always a second pole, even in monopolar stimulation, it just may not be particularly close to the first one.

Comment: @BryanKrause Although physically the current would flow, my answer was a bit misleading with respect to what you say, as a second electrode is indeed used even for monopolar stimulation, so I've amended it.